# Stop Angular inserting [object Object] into my text input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angular to filter an array of data for a table. The filter works on the table but when I select one of the select options it inserts [object Object] into my text input. How do I stop this?

```
<div class='table-filters'>

  <div class='row'>
    <label>Search</label>
    <input ng-model="query"   name='search' >
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <label for='category'>Category</label>
    <select ng-model="query.cat">
      <option value="">Any</option>
      <option value="VOWEL">Vowels</option>
      <option value="CONSONANT">Consonants</option>
      <option value="NUMBER">Digits</option>
      <option value="SIGN: DEP">Dependent Signs</option>
      <option value="SIGN: IND">Independent Signs</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class='row'>
    <label for='matched-rows'>Matched Characters</label>
    <span id='matched-rows'>{{(rows|filter:query).length}}</span<
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found a solution form this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/XklvXtc1AZpndjLvXrh8?p=preview;

```
<div class='row'>
 <label>Search</label>
 <input ng-model="query[queryBy]"   name='search' >
</div>
```

js file:

```
demo.controller('demoController', function($scope){

    $scope.rows = getRows();
    $scope.query = {};
    $scope.queryBy = '$';

});
```

I should have put my js file in the question, I know. Apologies for the poorly written question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

query is Object and its toString() implementation returns [object Object].

Use query.cat as ng-model for input.

```
<input ng-model="query.cat"   name='search' >
```

Comment: but won't that restrict the search to just .cat property. I won't to be able to filter the array against all properties not just the .cat.

Comment: But in that case you don't need input. Just use your query object and do filtering. From what I see you will have to define custom filtering method.